# mongodb design database for comment approval in high volume of writing

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I have an issue with designing a comment collection  in mongo db.

I am trying to build user public profile page that allow any visitor to comment on the user page. However, the user needs to approve/disapprove the comment in order to show it in his public  profile page .

I am expecting a high volume of writing comment to the user page. And only user will read pending(unapproved) comment.

I came with two solutions :

1. Separate the comment collection  to two collection :

   A. Comment pending  collection:
   Which contains all pending comments.

   B. Comment approved collection :
   Which contains all approved comment by the user.
2. Adding boolean value "is_approved" for all comments and then indexing that value. And search for it.

The first Solution needs from me to  handle removing pending comments from pending comment collection  when approved and adding it to the  approved collection collection.

While the second solution, I don't know if it works or not .

Any advise in this case for best collection design of reading comments ?

Comment: @joe-drumgoole  Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend 2nd approach with boolean value. But you need to make sure you are handling it properly at your code level.

First approach will mess up your data once your database will grow and it will be very difficult to maintain two collection for one thing.